# stuck on jpg image forensics task

Tags: jpeg, steganography, computer-forensics, ctf

I am trying to understand a jpg forensics problem, the organizers mentioned that i need to change 1 or a few bytes in the ff c0 segment, i can't seem to figure it out at all, the name of the challenge is no_limts and description says you need to go deeper

Relevant segment

```
00000100: 0c0c ffc0 0011 0801 a001 6703 0122 0002  ..........g.."..
0000ffc0: ac85 64e2 1969 6fb5 06b3 b392 6646 da83  ..d..io.....fF..
```

Exif tools

```
ExifTool Version Number         : 11.88
File Name                       : shrek1.jpg
Directory                       : .
File Size                       : 76 kB
File Modification Date/Time     : 2023:11:30 22:05:02+05:30
File Access Date/Time           : 2023:11:30 22:05:08+05:30
File Inode Change Date/Time     : 2023:11:30 22:05:02+05:30
File Permissions                : rw-rw-r--
File Type                       : JPEG
File Type Extension             : jpg
MIME Type                       : image/jpeg
JFIF Version                    : 1.01
Exif Byte Order                 : Big-endian (Motorola, MM)
Orientation                     : Horizontal (normal)
X Resolution                    : 1
Y Resolution                    : 1
Resolution Unit                 : None
Y Cb Cr Positioning             : Centered
Image Width                     : 65535
Image Height                    : 511
Encoding Process                : Baseline DCT, Huffman coding
Bits Per Sample                 : 8
Color Components                : 255
Image Size                      : 65535x511
Megapixels                      : 33.5
```

I tried reading the lsb encoding, tried using binwalk, tried strings

Comment: What is your question? (and can it be solved by programming?) We don't have the image, we cannot experiment with changing things to see what happens. And this challenge is supposed to test you, why bring it to us?

Comment: But have a cryptic hint about one thing to examine: 2l7nbRlFM7g

Comment: See **SOF0** here... https://www.ccoderun.ca/programming/2017-01-31_jpeg/

Answer (score -1):

Solved it by changing the components field to 4 and increasing the height field

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).